# Passing variable to href tag

Tags: html, twig

I'm developping a twig template in which I would need to set a href tag with a twig variable.

I tried the following :

```
{% for key in tab|keys %}
    <li><a href="'#' + '{{ key }}'"> {{ key }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work, do you have an idea bout how to do ?

Comment: Try removing the `'` and `+` characters: `<a href="#{{ key }}">{{ key }}</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#{{key}}">{{key}}</a>
```

instead of this:

```
<a href="'#' + '{{ key }}'"> {{ key }} </a>
```

Comment: @user2302725 - If this solved your problem you should consider voting it up and mark it as correct.